# Create a table and insert data into that table in one function PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a function that creates a table, inserts data into this table and then calculates the average value of this table.
Currently, I can do this by making a table beforehand and then run the function. But I would like to have a single function that does all of this.  When I run the function I get the following response:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function loop_time_v(bigint) line 16 at SQL statement
```

And here is the function I am taliking about:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_time (n bigint)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
a RECORD;
start_time timestamp with time zone := '2019-07-26 15:05:00+02'; 
end_time timestamp with time zone := (SELECT line_current_data.valid_for_timestamp FROM line_current_data ORDER BY valid_for_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1);
interval_num bigint := (select extract(epoch from (end_time::timestamp with time zone - '2019-07-26 15:05:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))/ 300);

BEGIN

    CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE interval_avg (valid_for_timestamp timestamp with time zone, device_inst_id bigint, i_n double precision);

    FOR a IN 1..interval_num LOOP 


        INSERT INTO interval_avg
        SELECT
            valid_for_timestamp,
            device_inst_id,
            value
        FROM  line_current_data
        WHERE line_current_data.valid_for_timestamp > (start_time + ((a - 1) * interval '5 min'))
        AND   line_current_data.valid_for_timestamp <= (start_time + (a * interval '5 min'))
        AND   line_current_data.device_inst_id >= 1097
        AND      line_current_data.device_inst_id <= 1201;


        INSERT INTO avg_line_current
        SELECT
            (start_time + (a * interval '5 min')),
            device_inst_id,
            avg(i_n)
        FROM interval_avg
        GROUP BY device_inst_id;

        DELETE FROM interval_avg;

        RAISE NOTICE '%', a;

    END LOOP;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Fertik';

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Make your table 'interval_avg ' temporary and create your definitive table with 'create table 'your_table_name' as select * from 'your_temp_table_name'.